# How to get laser data of Hokuyo UST-20LX

Tags: ros, laser, ethernet, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hokuyo UST-20LX 's data interface is Ethernet 100base-TX. I have installed Hokuyo node, but Ethernet interface is not a serial port device, so the /dev/ttyACM0 didn't show up. Is there any drivers for that device under ROS? How can I get the data of UST-20LX?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190436/how-to-get-laser-data-of-hokuyo-ust-20lx/) by [Thomaswang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12811/thomaswang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-18**:
Can you try urg_node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

urg_node is the correct option.  Should be as simple as installing it (apt-get or what have you), and then running it, specifying an IP address.

rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:=192.168.0.10  (the ip address is the factory default).

---

Originally posted by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) with karma: 422 on 2014-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2